# Creating A Bitcoin Wallet for my WordPress Site

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, wallet, blockchain.info, website-integration

I'm a new web programmer and I'm building a website. When a user signs up, he is given a Bitcoin Wallet.... so he can send bitcoins to the wallet and the Website tells him how much he has, I would also like to  add the feature for the user to send Bitcoin to other wallets but with a form of Escrow first.